# Jasmine unit testing current context or this var

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have been looking in to this article for Jasmine unit testing. I found this example:

```
describe("Episode", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.episode = new Backbone.Model({
      title: "Hollywood - Part 2"
    });
  });

  it("should expose an attribute", function() {
    expect(this.episode.get("title"))
      .toEqual("Hollywood - Part 2");
  });
});
```

This example is using **this.episode** in `beforeEach`and `it`. As far as I know JS doesn't work like this. `this.episode` doesn't work in describe block at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasmine introduced a new way to share variables between `beforeEach`, `it`, and `afterEach` through `this` keyword.

You should also know that each spec’s `beforeEach`, `it`, `afterEach` has `this` as the same empty object that is set back to empty for the next spec.

**[From Github](https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303)**

> For every test (and their beforeEach/afterEach hooks), jasmine sets
>   the receiver of each function to an initially empty object. This
>   object, which is called userContext within Jasmine's source code, can
>   have properties assigned to it, and gets blown away at the end of each
>   test. In an attempt to address the issues we were having, we recently
>   switched over to assigning variables to this object, rather than
>   declaring them within describe and then assigning them.

This new approach is considered better because of:

- No more global leaks
- Clear meaning
- Improved code reuse via dynamic invocation
- Reduced Code Duplication via Lazy Evaluation